# Prevent copy of shared pointer on return

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, return-value-optimization

I have a container derived from `std::map` that holds shared pointers, and a custom method for looking up elements, similar to the code below.

The container does not change while I use it, and I would like the lookup to return the shared pointer without making a copy, and not increment the pointer's counter. How can I ensure this?

```
struct X;    
using Xp = std::shared_ptr< X >;

struct Xs : std::map< int, Xp >
{
  Xp get( int n ) const {
    auto p = find( n );
    return p != end() ? p->second : nullptr;
  }
};

Xs xs;

void test() {
  // always increments the counter of the shared_ptr :(
  if( auto const& p = xs.get( 5 ) )
    ( void ) p;
}
```

Edit: I cannot change the container and I cannot return a raw pointer. Is there no way to return a reference to the pointer without changing it?

Comment: `and not increment the pointer's counter` that's what smart pointers do, otherwise you should probably use raw pointer.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a copy of the shared pointer? That's kind of the point of it, that you can have many different shared pointer copies, but they all point to the same single object. Your question, as it is right now, has the distinct smell of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you're not storing the copy, it's fairly pointless. This is a fair question.

Comment: If you're not storing the copy, the counter should also decrement all by itself. But this code is storing the copy for the duration of the if block. So the counter should get incremented, and it will decrement again after the if block is done.

Comment: You can return a `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: `std::weak_ptr` is definitely the right answer here. If you don't intend to add extra ownership, this is exactly why `std::weak_ptr` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use null object to allow to return reference:

```
struct Xs : std::map< int, Xp >
{
  const Xp& get( int n ) const {
    static const Xp nullObject{nullptr};
    auto p = find( n );
    return p != end() ? p->second : nullObject;
  }
};
```